# amcharts angular zoomlevelchanged event

Tags: amcharts

When I click on a country the zoomlevelchanged event is fired a hundred times! I expect that it fires a maximum of 2 times.

Is that intentional or did I do something wrong?

I wanted to provide a codepen sample post however it will break if I insert the code below:

```
  chart.events.on("zoomlevelchanged", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

The event shouldn't be triggered that often in my opinion because it will take some resource if it needs to compute s.th. based on the zoom level.

Is it possible to use another event to react when somebody zoomed in the map? It shouldn't be bound by the direction of the zoom like up or down and also it shouldn't be different between mouse and smartphone inputs.

The complete code:

```
import { Component, NgZone, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4maps from "@amcharts/amcharts4/maps";
import am4geodata_worldLow from "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata/worldLow";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  private chart: am4maps.MapChart;

  constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      // create map instance
      let chart = am4core.create("mapdiv", am4maps.MapChart);

      // set map definition
      chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;

      // set projection
      chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

      // Create map polygon series
      var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());

      // Configure series
      let polygonTemplate = this.configureTemplate(polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template);

      // Make map load polygon (like country names) from GeoJSON
      polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;

      // Use data instead for additional information
      polygonSeries.data = [{
        "id": "US",
        "name": "United States",
        "value": 100,
        "fill": am4core.color("#F05C5C")
      }, {
        "id": "FR",
        "name": "France",
        "value": 50,
        "fill": am4core.color("#5C5CFF")
      }];


      polygonTemplate.propertyFields.fill = "fill";

      // exclude antarktika
      polygonSeries.exclude = ["AQ"];

      // include germany only
      // polygonSeries.include = ["DE"];

      // ImageSeries (for adding visual objects like markers)
      let imageSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapImageSeries());
      // Basic Circle Image
      let imageSeriesTemplate = imageSeries.mapImages.template;
      let circle = imageSeriesTemplate.createChild(am4core.Circle);
      circle.radius = 4;
      circle.fill = am4core.color("#B27799");
      circle.stroke = am4core.color("#FFFFFF");
      circle.strokeWidth = 2;
      circle.nonScaling = true;
      circle.tooltipText = "{title}";

      // Binding Marker Properties to Data
      imageSeriesTemplate.propertyFields.latitude = "latitude";
      imageSeriesTemplate.propertyFields.longitude = "longitude";

      // Adding 3 Markers to the Map
      imageSeries.data = [{
        "latitude": 48.856614,
        "longitude": 2.352222,
        "title": "Paris"
      }, {
        "latitude": 40.712775,
        "longitude": -74.005973,
        "title": "New York"
      }, {
        "latitude": 49.282729,
        "longitude": -123.120738,
        "title": "Vancouver"
      }];

      // Adding Zoom Controls
      // chart.zoomControl = new am4maps.ZoomControl();

      // Heat map based on the value property in data
      // polygonSeries.heatRules.push({
      //   "property": "fill",
      //   "target": polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template,
      //   "min": am4core.color("#ffffff"),
      //   "max": am4core.color("#AAAA00")
      // });


      chart.events.on("zoomlevelchanged", function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      });

      // chart code goes here
      this.chart = chart;

    });
  }

  configureTemplate(polygonTemplate) {
    // Create ToolTip
    polygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}";
    //  Fill Template Color
    polygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#BADA55");

    // Create hover state 
    let hoverState = polygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
    // set alternative Fill Color when hovering
    hoverState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#367B25");

    // show additional data in tooltip, akquired from polygonSeries.data
    polygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}: {value}";

    // Zooming to map area on click
    polygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function(ev){
      ev.target.series.chart.zoomToMapObject(ev.target)
    });

    return polygonTemplate;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      if (this.chart) {
        this.chart.dispose();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, Codepen uses its own version of `console.log` which breaks with AmCharts objects due to circular references. You should consider using `console.dir` instead. That said, I agree that the behavior is weird. I've raised this internally since there isn't a way to do this very easily at the moment.

Comment: It fires a lot as the `zoomLevel` is animating in steps, i.e. incrementing/decrementing gradually towards the target zoomLevel. You can consider tracking changes in the zoomLevel to determine if the user is zooming in/out. Consider debouncing the event handler to limit the executions if need be.